# Unable to map javascript array in struts 2 action as List<String>

Tags: javascript, arrays, list, struts2, mapping

In an html page, I have checkboxes like following:

```
<input name="serviceareas" type="checkbox" id="cb1" value="1">
<input name="serviceareas" type="checkbox" id="cb2" value="2">
...
```

with the help of jquery I create javascript array of values for all the checked checkboxes

```
getSelectedValues : function() {
            var allVals = [];
            $('#checkboxTable :checked').each(function() {
                   allVals.push($(this).val());
              });
            //alert("allVals: "+allVals);

            return allVals;
        }
```

, and sends it to Struts 2 Action. For example in firebug request, I see :-

**serviceareas  21,26,30**

In the Action I have tried mapping it to

```
private List<String> serviceareas = new ArrayList<String>();
```

But instead SOP is printing it as an Object and it isn't able to cast it to java List

```
public class CreateEventAction extends ActionSupport {

    private List<String> serviceareas = new ArrayList<String>();

    public List<String> getServiceareas() {
        return serviceareas;
    }
    public void setServiceareas(List<String> serviceareas) {
        this.serviceareas = serviceareas;
    }

    @Override
    public String execute() throws Exception {

        if(this.serviceareas != null) {

                for (String serviceAreaId : this.serviceareas) {

                        System.out.println("String :"+serviceAreaId);

                }

            }

        return SUCCESS;
    }
```

Output:
**String :21,26,30**

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: How are you creating the javascript array? Can you show that code. Also why do you need to create an array when you can submit the checkboxes in a form? Also this should work `actionUrl?serviceareas=21,26,30`

Comment: @Anu - I am not very good in JS, but I can tell you what I am doing. Instead of submitting the form, I am making an ajax call. I have pasted above the javascript function creating array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you submit to action works, try to construct your parameters like that:

```
serviceareas=21&serviceareas=26&serviceareas=30
```

Answer (score 1):

[Aleksandr M's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13175526/456135) should work. I am posting this answer just to make it more clear how to implement it.

Instead of submiting javascript array, submit a string.

```
getSelectedValues : function() {
    var allVals = '';
    $('#checkboxTable :checked').each(function() {
         allVals += "serviceareas="+$(this).val()+"&";  //prepare the string
    });
    if(allVals.length>0){
         allVals = allVals.substring(0,allVals.length-1); //remove last '&'
    }    
    return allVals; //submit this string as parameter
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I will give it a go and let you know by tomorrow.

Comment: Thanks @anu for the above method. I really appreciate :)

Answer (score 0):

I think this is not possible. When you submit a form which has a check box or multiple list in the servlet we normally call `getPrameterValues()` , this method internally convert the coma seperated string to and array and returns it as an array of string. But here in your case you just submit a coma separated string and action servlet call interanlly call `getPrameter()` , so it will be a sting there and initilaise your List with one string. to get it done you will have to submit the form which has the checkbox group.

here you can do a quick fix by spliting this coma separated string in your action class ....or you need to find out the way how you can submit  with respective property in your actionFor( struts 1.2). Let me have a quick refferences of struts 2. anyhow the current approach is wrong.

Comment: since all checkboxes have same name i.e. name="serviceareas", it is actually a checkbox group, isn't it?